# difference between step up and step down transformer

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

In our school textbook it was written that there are two types of transformers step up and step down. But what is there structural difference and is there any other type of transformer?

Comment: Isolation transformers are 1:1, so no step up or down. The structural differences are pretty minimal, and in non-demanding applications you can run a step-up transformer 'backwards' to step down. (For years I ran a European 240V stereo on 120V US power using a suitably doctored 240-120 step-down transformer to step up instead).

Comment: This is why I dislike high school physics texts for the most part. They create non-existent categories. Better to say there are three main applications for transformers: voltage step-up, voltage step-down, and isolation. The specific application may determine minor engineering design differences, but they all use magnetic induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question is about the type of transformer, i am not going to discuss the detail the construction of it, rather the underlying principle. In practices transformer has two component namely primary and secondary. For an ideal transformer energy must conserved.
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{p} & = & P_{s} \\
\Rightarrow V_{p}I_{p} &  = & V_{s}I_{s}\qquad\text{as}\qquad \boxed{P=VI}\\
\text{or},\frac{V_{p}}{V_{s}} & = & \frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}}\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Where, $V_{p},I_{p}$ are the voltage and current in the primary circuit and $V_{s},I_{s}$ are that for secondary circuit respectively. If consider the number of turns of the coil in primary ($N_{p}$) and secondary circuit ($N_{s}$), then expression (1) further extends to
$$\frac{V_{p}}{V_{s}}  =  \frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}}=\frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}\tag{2}$$
Equation (2) is the main equation for transformer.

Now consider $$\frac{V_{p}}{V_{s}}  = \frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}$$

Case-1: If $N_{p}>N_{s}$ then $V_{s}<V_{p}$. This the **step-down** transformer. Where the number of turns in the primary is greater than that of secondary.

Case-2:If $N_{s}>N_{p}$ then $V_{s}>V_{p}$. This the **step-up** transformer. Where the number of turns in the primary is less than that of secondary.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between a step-up and step-down transformer form construction and working principle point of view. In fact a transformer can only be said Step-up or step-down when it is put in service. Therefore, the difference between them arises from operational point of view. Step-up transformer increase the voltage with corresponding decrease in current. Whereas step-down transformer decreases the voltage with increase in current. The difference is really well explained at "[difference between a step-up and step-down transformer](https://electricalbaba.com/difference-step-up-step-down-transformer/)" Just loved the way the thing is explained.

Answer (score 0):

One difference if you can see the windings is that the lower voltage coil will be made with thicker wire because if the voltage is stepped down the current is stepped up.  The thicker windings are there to reduce the resistance and hence the heat loss.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to know about transformer equation it is as follows 
(N1/N2)=(V1/V2)=(I2/I1) it says that input power is equal to output power the winding to which power is given is known as primary winding and from which output is taken is called as secondary winding in above equation N represents no.of turns of the transformer V is the voltage and I is the current the step up or step down is based on input and output voltage if output voltages is more than input it is called step up transformer if output is less than input voltage it called as step down they can be interchanged as it depends on no.of turns if output is taken where it has more turns then it becomes step up transformer else it becomes step down transformer if a transformer has same turns it is called auto transformer.main point to keep in mind is transformer works on mutual induction principle and it is a passive device it's input and output power is same for ideal case but in practical it has some loses hence output power is always less than input power. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is, in principle, no difference. You can use a *step-up* transformer by interchanging the input and output coil contacts also as a *step-down* transformer. The ratio of windings gives yo the ratio of voltages and of the inverse of the currents, so that instant input power approximately equals output power $V_1 I_1=V_2 I_2$. Therefore, the coil with the smaller number of windings often has a thicker wire to reduce the resistive power loss at high currents.